# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity and skipping frames

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working on an android Temperature converter app(which does not work). At first I saw this message on LogCat

> the application may be doing too much work on its main thread

I then removed the code that was never used.

Now, this is the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

### Code: Main_Activity.java

```
package com.example.tempconverter;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    final EditText editCelsius = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCelsius);
    final EditText editFahrenheit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFahrenheit);
    Button buttonConvert =(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);

    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double celsius = Double.valueOf(editCelsius.getText().toString());
            double fahrenheit = (celsius * 9)/5 +32;
            editFahrenheit.setText(String.valueOf(fahrenheit));


        }
    });
}
}
```

The code in fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tempconverter.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textCelsius"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:text="Celsius"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    tools:ignore="hardcodedtext" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editCelsius"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textCelsius"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textCelsius"
    android:ems="7"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textFahrenheit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editCelsius"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:text="Fahrenheit"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    tools:ignore="hardcodedtext" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editFahrenheit"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:text="Convert"
    tools:ignore="hardcodedtext" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editFahrenheit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editCelsius"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textFahrenheit"
    android:ems="7"
    android:inputType="number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is a part of the LogCat now ...
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxd5Rg3QFBfbdkZULWxNUTVrV2M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the logcat don't contains something of useful here, you should post the logcat when crash (but the text, not an image)

Comment: Do you mean that I should select "verbose" instead of "errors"?

Comment: Check if your ids on the layout correspond with your `findViewById` methods.

Comment: Nope, i mean: Launch your app, when it crash go to eclipse and paste where the output

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you are inflating the wrong view. You've got a `RuntimeException`, and you should have a `NullPointerException`, because the `setContentView` try to set (and methods `findViewById` try to find views inside) the wrong layout as:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

whereas all your `EditText`s, `TextView`s and `Buttons` are in `fragment_main.xml`.
Try to set the content view as follow:

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

or, rename `fragment_main.xml` to `activity_main.xml`.

---

**Update from comments:**

These kinds of errors *"Couldn't load memtrack module'* occur with **some** devices with emulator. To avoid this, always test with **multiple** devices (real or not).

Comment: I've tried this one:           setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);  I got the same error message "couldn't load memtrack module"

Comment: @Rsaleh you did this on emulator? Did you try on real device?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I changed the "Run Configurations" and it works fine now :')

Comment: @Rsaleh Glad to help! Sometimes the emulator with **some** devices have these kinds of errors: "couldn't load memtrack module". Apparently, it's a current error with emulators. To avoid, test with multiple devices (real or not).

Comment: @Rsaleh Thank you to accept my answer. You did the most part to resolve your issue, I just gave the clue. +1 to this, bravo! Happy coding.